# Processing files make my program go into non-responding mode. New Process or New thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, imagemagick, qt-creator

I made an application using Qt where I manipulate Images using the Magick++ library.

The problem is when I'm trying to apply the effects into a list of images, the programs stops responding until the processing is done, I guess that is very normal but I also guess that there should be a solution using new process? concurrency perhaps?

This is the code that is being executed when I'm processing images.

```
foreach (QFileInfo f, list)
 {

  Image image;
  image.read(qPrintable(f.absoluteFilePath()));

  try {

      //Apply effects effects
      image.addNoise(GaussianNoise);
      image.magick("png");
      image.rotate(90);  
      image.write("//users//files//");
      }

  catch ( Magick::Exception & error)
  {
     // Displaying any possible errors on the text browser
     ui->textBrowser_error->setText(error.what());

  }

}
```

Can anyone show me a code hint that can help me avoid my program by going into non-responding mode?

**This is the current solution(Thanks to OneOfOne)**

```
void ClassName::processAll() {
    QList<QFileInfo> files = list;
 QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(files, &ClassName::processImage);
}

 void ClassName::processImage(QFileInfo & f) {
    Image image;
    image.read(qPrintable(f.absoluteFilePath()));

try {
     //   Apply effects effects
        image.magick("png");
        image.rotate(90);
        image.write("//Users//macmini//Desktop//files");
    } catch ( Magick::Exception & error) {
        // Displaying any possible errors on the text browser. 
        /* ui->textBrowser_error->setText(error.what());  <- This will not run so I had to commented out */

    }
}
```

This makes my program compile but after that I get a runtime error from apple:

```
    Process:         ProgramName [2801]
    Path:            /Users/macmini/ProgramName-build-desktop/ProgramName.app/Contents/MacOS/ProgramName
    Identifier:      com.yourcompany.ProgramName
    Version:         ??? (???)
    Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:  Qt Creator [2630]

    Date/Time:       2010-12-13 18:55:54.381 +0000
    OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.5 (10H574)
    Report Version:  6

    Interval Since Last Report:          459149 sec
    Crashes Since Last Report:           54
    Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  59953 sec
    Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   16
    Anonymous UUID:                      2FA19EA1-D3CE-479B-B074-AB6A297BEFCF

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
    Crashed Thread:  7

    Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83a9927d -[NSConcreteMapTable objectForKey:] + 1
    1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80f670df -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 1104
    2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80f66ab0 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 254
    3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80f63362 -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2683
    4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80edcb9a -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 969
    5   QtGui                           0x0000000100346cca -[QCocoaWindow displayIfNeeded] + 250
    6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80ed7a46 _handleWindowNeedsDisplay + 678
    7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86644b37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 519
    8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86620464 __CFRunLoopRun + 468
    9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8661fdbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
    10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff840a291a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
    11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff840a267d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 148
    12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff840a25d8 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
    13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80eace64 _DPSNextEvent + 718
    14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80eac7a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
    15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff80e7248b -[NSApplication run] + 395
    16  QtGui                           0x0000000100354344 QEventDispatcherMac::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 1588
    17  QtCore                          0x00000001010bde54 QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 68
    18  QtCore                          0x00000001010be174 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 180
    19  QtCore                          0x00000001010bf79c QCoreApplication::exec() + 188
    20  com.yourcompany.ProgramName     0x00000001000031cb main + 107
    21  com.yourcompany.ProgramName     0x0000000100002fb6 _start + 224
    22  com.yourcompany.ProgramName     0x0000000100002ed5 start + 33

    Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061a16a kevent + 10
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061c03d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061bd14 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
    3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061b83e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
    4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061b168 _pthread_wqthread + 353
    5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061b005 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 2:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff80644e92 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
    1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86642498 __CFSocketManager + 824
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8063a536 _pthread_start + 331
    3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8063a3e9 thread_start + 13

    Thread 3:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061a16a kevent + 10
    1   QtCore                          0x00000001010aae8a QKqueueFileSystemWatcherEngine::run() + 154
    2   QtCore                          0x00000001010064cf QThreadPrivate::start(void*) + 175
    3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8063a536 _pthread_start + 331
    4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8063a3e9 thread_start + 13

    Thread 4:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061af8a __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061b39c _pthread_wqthread + 917
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061b005 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 5:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061af8a __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061b39c _pthread_wqthread + 917
    2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8061b005 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 6:

    Thread 7 Crashed:
    0   libMagickCore.4.dylib           0x000000010144068c gomp_resolve_num_threads + 28
    1   libMagickCore.4.dylib           0x00000001012c5d95 AcquirePixelCache + 309
    2   libMagickCore.4.dylib           0x000000010137be02 AcquireImage + 370
    3   libMagick++.4.dylib             0x00000001002b5057 Magick::ImageRef::ImageRef() + 87
    4   libMagick++.4.dylib             0x00000001002ab742 Magick::Image::Image() + 50
    5   com.yourcompany.ProgramName     0x00000001000047e1 ProgramName::processImage(QFileInfo&) + 33
    6   com.yourcompany.ProgramName     0x0000000100008d1d QtConcurrent::MapKernel<QList<QFileInfo>::iterator, QtConcurrent::FunctionWrapper1<void, QFileInfo&> >::runIteration(QList<QFileInfo>::iterator, int, void*) + 13
    7   com.yourcompany.ProgramName     0x0000000100009238 QtConcurrent::MapKernel<QList<QFileInfo>::iterator, QtConcurrent::FunctionWrapper1<void, QFileInfo&> >::runIterations(QList<QFileInfo>::iterator, int, int, void*) + 72
    8   com.yourcompany.ProgramName     0x000000010000974d QtConcurrent::IterateKernel<QList<QFileInfo>::iterator, void>::threadFunction() + 573
    9   QtCore                          0x0000000100fffcb9 QtConcurrent::ThreadEngineBase::run() + 57
    10  QtCore                          0x0000000101002425 QThreadPoolThread::run() + 117
    11  QtCore                          0x00000001010064cf QThreadPrivate::start(void*) + 175
    12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8063a536 _pthread_start + 331
    13  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8063a3e9 thread_start + 13

    Thread 8:
    0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8063a3dc thread_start + 0

    Thread 7 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
      rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000002148
      rdi: 0x0000000000000104  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000116580b10  rsp: 0x0000000116580b00
       r8: 0x0000000101b6e000   r9: 0x0000000116580b00  r10: 0x00007fffffe00050  r11: 0x0000000102b6c600
      r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000102b28000  r14: 0x0000000102b82a68  r15: 0x0000000116580d00
      rip: 0x000000010144068c  rfl: 0x0000000000010297  cr2: 0x0000000000000010

    Binary Images:
           0x100000000 -        0x100290fe7 +com.yourcompany.ProgramName ??? (???) <688ECF56-94E8-00A4-B958-94612C902F9F> /Users/macmini/ProgramName-build-desktop/ProgramName.app/Contents/MacOS/ProgramName
           0x10029b000 -        0x1002dcff7 +libMagick++.4.dylib 5.0.0 (compatibility 5.0.0) <51C6408C-04BD-548B-E2FC-F112252FA2BD> /opt/local/lib/libMagick++.4.dylib
           0x100317000 -        0x100ceafef +QtGui 4.7.0 (compatibility 4.7.0) <BD43BAAD-873D-45E8-3605-1E344992BB51> /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
           0x100f92000 -        0x101217fef +QtCore 4.7.0 (compatibility 4.7.0) <AEA4A1B9-46B8-7621-8D00-555040D89C56> /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
           0x1012ab000 -        0x101482ff7 +libMagickCore.4.dylib 5.0.0 (compatibility 5.0.0) <25912B2F-55D0-2DA9-DBBF-43986B432952> /opt/local/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib
           0x10151d000 -        0x10162efff +libMagickWand.4.dylib 5.0.0 (compatibility 5.0.0) <80E63BB5-E18A-2BAB-7AFF-D3037AE57427> /opt/local/lib/libMagickWand.4.dylib
           0x10164c000 -        0x101679fe7 +liblcms.1.dylib 2.19.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <2B45C260-15E9-151E-4C8A-05D6B402522B> /opt/local/lib/liblcms.1.dylib
           0x101686000 -        0x1016dffff +libtiff.3.dylib 13.4.0 (compatibility 13.0.0) <262BF250-EA47-62E2-D6CB-573CB1E8DD6D> /opt/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib
           0x1016ec000 -        0x101721ff7 +libjpeg.8.dylib 9.2.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <055E3C7A-A428-2298-816E-79D4279DEE25> /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
           0x101728000 -        0x101756ff7 +libfontconfig.1.dylib 6.4.0 (compatibility 6.0.0) <ABE342A5-D352-6D3E-D588-60CEE60396EA> /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
           0x101761000 -        0x101780fef +libexpat.1.dylib 7.2.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <4F23C4ED-72D8-5478-FBBC-5DC01F8E4752> /opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
           0x101787000 -        0x101807fff +libfreetype.6.dylib 13.1.0 (compatibility 13.0.0) <1DBA7D79-C80E-B3F6-6BEF-5ECBBB318ADE> /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
           0x10181c000 -        0x101918fe7 +libiconv.2.dylib 8.0.0 (compatibility 8.0.0) <6907D6DB-2535-7725-484F-74378F42AFED> /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
           0x101925000 -        0x101933ff7 +libXext.6.dylib 11.0.0 (compatibility 11.0.0) <CB09409A-FEA2-3CF5-769A-127ECCCE2963> /opt/local/lib/libXext.6.dylib
           0x101939000 -        0x101986fe7 +libXt.6.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <D780E06E-3060-3D13-BCEC-2F297E840939> /opt/local/lib/libXt.6.dylib
           0x10199e000 -        0x1019acfff +libbz2.1.0.dylib 1.0.6 (compatibility 1.0.0) <B2276F4D-BAC5-E9C3-690C-DCC478079569> /opt/local/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
           0x1019b1000 -        0x1019c5ff7 +libz.1.dylib 1.2.5 (compatibility 1.0.0) <6D767FC2-DF89-6017-4B82-A1E5EB8CEED9> /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib
           0x1019c9000 -        0x1019cbff7  libclparser.dylib ??? (???) <9985A543-86E9-DA9E-3B97-80CA7AAE84A1> 
--Code Removed-- It didnt fit!

/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
        0x7fff85f7e000 -     0x7fff85ffdfe7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <1DD64A62-0DE4-223F-F781-B272FECF80F0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
        0x7fff85ffe000 -     0x7fff86083ff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <CDFE82DD-D811-A091-179F-6E76069B432D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
        0x7fff86084000 -     0x7fff86588fe7  com.apple.VideoToolbox 0.484.20 (484.20) <8B6B82D2-350B-E9D3-5433-51453CDA65B4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Versions/A/VideoToolbox
        0x7fff865d4000 -     0x7fff8674bfe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.4 (550.42) <770C572A-CF70-168F-F43C-242B9114FCB5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
        0x7fff8674c000 -     0x7fff8679bff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.0 (6.0) <14FD0978-4BE0-336B-A19E-F388694583EB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
        0x7fff867e0000 -     0x7fff86821ff7  com.apple.CoreMedia 0.484.20 (484.20) <42F3B74A-F886-33A0-40EE-8399B12BD32A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia
        0x7fff86822000 -     0x7fff868c2fff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.1 (362.1) <2740103A-6C71-D99F-8C6F-FA264546AD8F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
        0x7fff868c3000 -     0x7fff868e4fff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <6993F348-428F-C97E-7A84-7BD2EDC46A62> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
        0x7fff868e5000 -     0x7fff86d28fef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
        0x7fff86d3f000 -     0x7fff86d55fe7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.10 (207.10) <1828C264-A54A-7FDD-FE1B-49DDE3F50779> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
        0x7fff86d56000 -     0x7fff86da7fef  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.1 (???) <BE479ABF-3D27-A5C7-800E-3FFC1731767A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
        0x7fff86de0000 -     0x7fff86e03fff  com.apple.opencl 12.3 (12.3) <D30A45FC-4520-45AF-3CA5-092313DB5D54> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
        0x7fff86e04000 -     0x7fff86ebafff  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <F206BE6D-8777-AE6C-B367-7BEA76C14241> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
        0x7fff86f54000 -     0x7fff86f6afff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.0.1 (6.0.1) <09ABF2E9-D110-71A9-4A6F-8A61B683E936> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
        0x7fff86f6b000 -     0x7fff86f9cfff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <57DA0064-4581-62B8-37A8-A07ADEF46EE2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
        0x7fff86f9d000 -     0x7fff86fa1ff7  libCGXType.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <63F77AC8-84CB-0C2F-8D2B-190EE5CCDB45> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
        0x7fff86fa2000 -     0x7fff86fc7ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
        0x7fff86fd4000 -     0x7fff86fedfff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <CCF79716-7CC6-2520-C6EB-A4F56AD0A207> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
        0x7fff86fee000 -     0x7fff870e6ff7  libiconv.2.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <7E4ADB5A-CC77-DCFD-3E54-2F35A2C8D95A> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
        0x7fff870e7000 -     0x7fff872a5fff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <781E7B63-2AD0-E9BA-927C-4521DB616D02> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
        0x7fff872a6000 -     0x7fff87643fe7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.34) <215222AF-B30A-7CE5-C46C-1A766C1D1D2E> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
        0x7fff87644000 -     0x7fff87646fff  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <CA8564FB-B366-7413-B12E-9892DA3C6157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
        0x7fff87682000 -     0x7fff8769dff7  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <FD46A0FE-AC79-3EF7-AB4F-396D376DDE71> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
        0x7fff8769e000 -     0x7fff8769ffff  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <EA4D1607-2BD5-2EE2-2A3B-632EEE5A444D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
        0x7fff876a0000 -     0x7fff876bdff7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <14043CBC-329F-4009-299E-DEE411E16134> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
        0x7fff87901000 -     0x7fff8794bff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.12) <9231045A-E2E3-B0C2-C81A-92C9EA98A4DF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
        0x7fff87af2000 -     0x7fff87b01fff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.1 (3.2.1) <FF21DB1E-F425-1005-FB70-BC19CAF4006E> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
        0x7fff87b11000 -     0x7fff87b8ffff  com.apple.CoreText 3.5.0 (???) <4D5C7932-293B-17FF-7309-B580BB1953EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
        0x7fff87ba9000 -     0x7fff87bf8fef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <AE9DC484-1382-F7AD-FE25-C28082FCB5D9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
        0x7fff87bf9000 -     0x7fff87cb2fff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <2C5ED312-E646-9ADE-73A9-6199A2A43150> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
        0x7fff87d3d000 -     0x7fff87d4eff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FB5EE53A-0534-0FFA-B2ED-486609433717> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
        0x7fff87ee8000 -     0x7fff88026fff  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <32233D4D-00B7-CE14-C881-6BF19FD05A03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
        0x7fff88027000 -     0x7fff88027ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
        0x7fff88028000 -     0x7fff88057ff7  com.apple.quartzfilters 1.6.0 (1.6.0) <9CECB4FC-1CCF-B8A2-B935-5888B21CBEEF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuartzFilters.framework/Versions/A/QuartzFilters
        0x7fff88058000 -     0x7fff8806afe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
        0x7fff880be000 -     0x7fff881e4fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.5 (1.6.5) <B51023BB-A5C9-3C65-268B-6B86B901BB2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
        0x7fff881e5000 -     0x7fff881ebfff  libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <4EE16374-A094-D542-5BC5-7E846D0CE56E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib
        0x7fff881ec000 -     0x7fff881eefff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <76438F90-DD4B-9941-9367-F2DFDF927876> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
        0x7fff881f5000 -     0x7fff881f5ff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <19B37B7B-1594-AD0A-7F14-FA2F85AD7241> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
        0x7fff881f6000 -     0x7fff88233ff7  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <8C69F685-3507-1B8F-51AD-6183D5E88979> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
        0x7fff88234000 -     0x7fff88237ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <38935851-09E4-DDAB-DB1D-30ADC39F7ED0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
        0x7fff88238000 -     0x7fff883a7fe7  com.apple.QTKit 7.6.6 (1756) <250AB242-816D-9F5D-94FB-18BF2AE9AAE7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit
        0x7fff8845f000 -     0x7fff88569ff7  com.apple.MeshKitIO 1.1 (49.2) <F296E151-80AE-7764-B969-C2050DF26BFE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MeshKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MeshKitIO.framework/Versions/A/MeshKitIO
        0x7fff8856a000 -     0x7fff8856eff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
        0x7fff885b3000 -     0x7fff885c4fff  com.apple.DSObjCWrappers.Framework 10.6 (134) <3C08225D-517E-2822-6152-F6EB13A4ADF9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework/Versions/A/DSObjCWrappers
        0x7fff885c5000 -     0x7fff88690fe7  ColorSyncDeprecated.dylib 4.6.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <3C223A94-EF14-28C5-844B-C25DFC87FB42> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ColorSyncDeprecated.dylib
        0x7fff88691000 -     0x7fff887b2fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <48AEAFE1-21F4-B3C8-4199-35AD5E8D0613> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
        0x7fff887b3000 -     0x7fff888cafef  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <EE067D7E-15B3-F043-6FBD-10BA31FE76C7> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
        0x7fff888cb000 -     0x7fff888d0fff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <9A2723D8-61F9-6D65-D254-4F9273CDA54A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
        0x7fff88c15000 -     0x7fff88c58ff7  libRIP.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <7E30B5F6-99FD-C716-8670-5DD4B4BAED72> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
        0x7fff88c59000 -     0x7fff88ca2fef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <EB4255DD-A9E5-FAD0-52A4-CCB4E792B86F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
        0x7fff88ca3000 -     0x7fff88ceffff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
        0x7fff88cf0000 -     0x7fff88d6dfef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
        0x7fff88d6e000 -     0x7fff88d82ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
        0x7fff88d83000 -     0x7fff88d84ff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <74800EE8-C14C-18C9-C208-20BBDB982D40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
        0x7fff88d85000 -     0x7fff88df1ff7  com.apple.CorePDF 1.3 (1.3) <6770FFB0-DEA0-61E0-3520-4B95CCF5D1CF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/Versions/A/CorePDF
        0x7fff88e6f000 -     0x7fff88e76fff  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <4200CFB0-DBA1-62B8-7C7C-91446D89551F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
        0x7fff88e77000 -     0x7fff890b2fef  com.apple.imageKit 2.0.3 (1.0) <5D18C246-303A-6580-9DC9-79BE79467C95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/ImageKit
        0x7fff890b3000 -     0x7fff890b3ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <DA9BFF01-40DF-EBD5-ABB7-787DAF2D77CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
        0x7fff890b4000 -     0x7fff890fbfff  com.apple.QuickLookFramework 2.3 (327.6) <11DFB135-24A6-C0BC-5B97-ECE352A4B488> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook
        0x7fff890fc000 -     0x7fff89127ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <87A0B228-B24A-C426-C3FB-B40D7258DD49> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
        0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <71E6D4C9-F945-6EC2-998C-D61AD590DAB6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

    Model: Macmini2,1, BootROM MM21.009A.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.19f0
    Graphics: Intel GMA 950, GMA 950, Built-In, spdisplays_integrated_vram
    Memory Module: global_name
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x86), Atheros 5424: 2.1.14.5
    Bluetooth: Version 2.3.8f7, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
    Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS541612J9SA00, 111.79 GB
    Parallel ATA Device: PIONEER DVD-RW  DVR-K06
    USB Device: A4 TECH USB2.0 PC Camera J, 0x0ac8  (Vimicro Corporation), 0xc40a, 0xfd600000
    USB Device: 2.4Ghz wireless combo sets, 0x04fc  (SUNPLUS TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD.), 0x05d8, 0x1d100000
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8205, 0x7d100000
    USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8240, 0x7d200000
```

Comment: Looking at the error looks like it crashes inside ImageMagick not the actual processImage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a processing function and use Qt4's [QtConcurrent::map](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtconcurrentmap.html#map) or [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtconcurrentrun.html#run).
Also check [QFuture](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qfuture.html).

Example:

```
void processImage(QFileInfo & f) {
    Image image;
    image.read(qPrintable(f.absoluteFilePath()));

    try {
        //Apply effects effects
        image.addNoise(GaussianNoise);
        image.magick("png");
        image.rotate(90);
        image.write("//users//files//");
    } catch ( Magick::Exception & error) {
        // Displaying any possible errors on the text browser
        ui->textBrowser_error->setText(error.what());

    }
}

void processAll() {
    const QList<QFileInfo> files = getFilesList();
    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(files, processImage);
    //do something with future
}
```

edit :: Changed QFile to QFileInfo.

Comment: Great!
The list variable I have containg QFileInfo objects.                   

I tried const QList<QFile> files = list;

but It gives me: error: conversion from 'QFileInfoList' to non-scalar type 'QList<QFile>' requested.       Any way to convert ?     10000 x Thanks

Comment: Change QList<QFile> to QList<QFileInfo>.

Comment: This is a Great answer OneOfOne.
It gives me: error: argument of type 'void (Classname::)(QFileInfo&)' does not match 'void (Classname::*)(QFileInfo&)'

any ideas?
10000 x 10000 Thanks

Comment: You can 1. use boost::bind (which I don't use much). 2. declare processImage static and go `QtConcurrent::map(files, &Classname::processImage)` or 3. use a struct like on the example page.

Comment: Great Advice OneOfOne!
I try not to deal with other library(boost)
Can you please tell me how to declare process Image as static?
It gives me: cannot declare member function 'void ClassName::processImage(QFileInfo&)' to have static linkage

Comment: in your header : static void processImage(QFileInfo & f);, in your source just void ClassName::processImage(QFileInfo & f) { /*code*/ };

Comment: errg :( that gives me: error: no match for call to '(QtConcurrent::FunctionWrapper1<void, QFileInfo&>) (const QFileInfo&)'     candidates are: T QtConcurrent::FunctionWrapper1<T, U>::operator()(U) [with T = void, U = QFileInfo&]  any ideas??

Comment: Looks like your process function is taking `const QFileInfo &` instead of just `QFileInfo &`, post some part of the code on pastebin if removing const doesn't fix it.

Comment: This time the program compiles! Thats great!
But Im getting an runtime error from apple when that function is executed! :(

Comment: Can you post the full code somewhere? can you use gdb and see where it crashes? try using QtCreator and use the debugger in it.

Comment: The debugger stop before creating this Image image; object with an error: could not access memory by signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: It might be related to ImageMagick, I have never used it so I can't really help. From your debug log it crashes in libMagickCore.4.dylib, Maybe it doesn't support threading, should ask in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works with Qt, but on Windows (WINAPI), a user interface stops responding when the message queue for that window goes unanswered for a period of time. Here's such a loop for completeness:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // if you don't handle this "fast" enough, windows "whites" you out
    switch ( msg )
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        // ...
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This happens if you're doing some heavy lifting processing one of those messages. That's what happens when a Windows window turns white, or grey, or whatever.

I've never worked with GUIs on Linux (I tend to write cli stuff) but I imagine it's the same principle.

You basically want to break out a new thread. However, *how* you do this is the interesting part.

If your app is linux-only, you could use pthreads or you could do:

```
pid_t result = fork()
if ( result == 0 )
{
    // child
}
elseif ( result > 0 )
{
    // parent, result = child process id.
}
else
{
    // error. result == -1.
}
```

As I understand it, there is little cost difference between a thread and a process on Linux.

However, some GUI frameworks provide their own thread wrappers I believe (wxWidgets comes to mind) for portability reasons. You might want to go with that if you're looking for a cross platform solution. I don't know if Qt provides such an option. However, before anyone else says it, Boost probably does.